# PhpStorm: How to resume debugging script to run to the end?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

I must be missing this but how to exit debug while letting the script run to the end? Clicking "resume" 30 times is one way. What's the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just **mute breakpoints** and then use `Resume` -- it will run the script till the end as if there were no user-set breakpoints (NOTE: programmatic breakpoints (e.g. `xdebug_break();`) *may* still stop the execution).

Just do not forget to unmute them later so you can have another debug session.

[image]

If you are often forgetting to unmute them -- consider activating `Unmute Breakpoints on Session Finish` option (available under "cog" icon in Debug tool window).

[image]